# Проблема с контроллером laravel

Tags: laravel

Начал учить `laravel`, как первый фреймворк и столкнулся с одной проблемой:

Файл `web.php`:

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');
```

файл `WelcomeController.php`:

```
<?
namespace App\Http\Controllers;



class WelcomeController extends Controller{

    function index(){

        return 'helloWorld!';
    }

}


?>
```

Сталкиваюсь с ошибкой

> Class App\Http\Controllers\WelcomeController does not exist

Подскажите, в чем дело?
Если это поможет - версия `laravel v5.4.23`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение проблемы. Удалил свой контроллер и пересоздал его при помощи artisan
php artisan make:controller WelcomeController

Получил следующий файл

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class WelcomeController extends Controller
{


    }
}
```

С ним уже и работал, все ок

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего автозагрузщик не может найти этот файл, проверьте точно ли файл ваш лежит в папке `app/Http/Controllers`.

Если же вы хотите контроллеры ложить в другое место, не в `app/Http/Controllers` нужно указывать полный путь к нему или поменять неймспейс по умолчанию в `RouteServiceProvider.php`

UPD. Ещё в вашем случае нужно объявить метод публичным, напишите вот так:

```
public function index(){
  return 'helloWorld!';
}
```

Comment: Кажется, все правильно лежит
https://i.gyazo.com/5b6df12646c647846a733dd3a53fafc5.png

Comment: Объявил публичным, тоже ничего не изменило.
А разве метод "по-умолчанию" не является публичным, если его объявить без метода доступа?

Comment: @eliotee да, но так правильней, вы `composer.json` случайно не изменяли там где autoload?

Comment: Нет, только-только установил laravel через composer, кроме этих файлов я ничего не трогал

Comment: @eliotee там по умолчанию должен быть HomeController.php и Auth контроллеры, в routes/web.php если у вас версия 5.3+ рскоментить нужно Auth::routes() по моему и проверить будут ли эти контроллеры работать

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/234f22f43924a0f344ad60cd8bb27fcc.png
HomeController.php - не нашел
Auth контроллеры есть, но там везде только конструктор без других методов

Comment: @eliotee всё верно, там всё в треитах, но если введете `php artisan routes:web` то увидите что есть роуты, по структуре папок всё нормально вроде бы, осталась только мысль что где то русская буква C у вас в названии файла или класса

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь. Смог решить проблему создав контроллер при помощи artisan

Comment: @eliotee ну скорее всего в этом и была проблема, в русском символе

Comment: Точно не в русском символе, перепечатывал несколько раз заново названия :)

Comment: Тогда состается composer, хотя уже не важно :)